# function_score tries to use field from excluded index in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have three own indices: **A**, **B**, **C**. Additionally I have **.marvel-kibana** index. All documents in **A**, **B**, **C** indices have *global_priorty* field.

I was wondering, why despite having excluded all but ABC indices, elastic throws exception: **ElasticsearchException[Unable to find a field mapper for field [global_priorty]]** in **.marvel-kibana** index? Isn't that index excluded (included to no_match_filter by default)?

My code:

```
GET /_search
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "function_score": {
          "query": { ... },
          "functions": [ 
            {
              "field_value_factor": {
                "field": "global_priorty",
                "factor": 1,
                "modifier": "sqrt"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "indices": {
          "indices": [ "A", "B", "C" ],
          "filter": { ... },
          "no_match_filter": "none"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "indices_boost": { ... },
  "highlight": { ... }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Karol,

I am not sure you are achieving here what you intended. Listing index in indices filter doesn't automatically mean it's excluded from the search.

The filter works like this:
for the indices in the *indices* list use *filter*. For others use *no_match_filter*.

How does your *filter* look like?

The preferred way to search only selected indices is to use them in the search endpoint. Something like:

```
get /A,B,C/_search 
{
....
}
```

Word of caution: I remember having some problems with Java API while setting multiple indices and types. But it was ages ago, though.

You should give it a try!

Regards,
Karol

P.S. 
Powodzenia! BTW: Parafrazując: Wszystkie Karole to porządne chłopaki!

Comment: Other thought: you could also use a filter checking for existence of _global\_priority_, but using only required indices would certainly be more efficient.

Comment: Checking for the existing of `global_priority` does not work, at least not when using `field_value_factor`. For me, this resulted in `ElasticsearchException[Unable to find a field mapper for field [global_priotity]`.